# Server time issue

Tags: 16.04

AM using ubuntu 16.04 in AWS.

I have changed server time from UTC to Kuwait time, after that date command printing correct time as per the time zone.

```
$ date 
Sun Mar 3 06:46:19 +03 2019
```

But the problem is if I have set a cronjob 6: 40, and it will not run that time, its run only after3 hours. am not understating why it happens. I have changed time using below command sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata and select Aisai/Kuwait.

Comment: Have you rebooted server so all daemons / background processes have been restarted with the new time setup ?

Comment: no.. because, first time only i getting this issue, usually i will not restart for time zone change

Answer (score 1):

You may specify the time zone for a crontab entry separately from the *system* time zone. Different users may also have different time zones specified.

You can specify the timezone to use for crontab with the `CRON_TZ`. Simply place

```
CRON_TZ=Asia/Kuwait
```

on a line above the other crontab entries.

Comment: no... only two users are there root and ubuntu both r running same time zone